# java.lang.NullPointerException in my Java/JSP application

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am getting a **java.lang.NullPointerException** when I am redirecting the output from a Java class to a JSP page and cannot figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my the first **form page** of my JSP application:

```
<body>
    <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="formprocessing.jsp">
Enter 1st DATE: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=date1 SIZE=20><BR>
Enter 2nd DATE: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=date2 SIZE=20><BR>
Enter PARAM CODE: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=p_code SIZE=4>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
  </body>
```

The input values from here are then **set** onto the output page by this Java class:

```
package duplicaterecords;

public class UserData {

    String date1;
    String date2;
    String p_code;

    public void setDate1( String value )
    {
        date1 = value;
    }

    public void setDate2( String value )
    {
        date2 = value;
    }

    public void setP_code( String value )
    {
        p_code = value;
    }

    public String getDate1() { return date1; }

    public String getDate2() { return date2; }

    public String getP_code() { return p_code; }


}
```

This is my main **Java class from which I am trying to redirect the output to the JSP page**:

```
package duplicaterecords;

import java.io.* ;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

 /*to find duplicate records and their time stamps*/
public class duplicaterecords extends HttpServlet {
    public static void main(String[] args,HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
    int l,x=0,y=0,tow[],i=0,z=0,tower1=0,t=0;
    String p_code,date[],date1,date2,getdate,date3,tower,t_split;

    String time2;
    tow=new int[1000];
    date=new String[100];

     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
     try
         {  

                                  BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //input buffer 
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                  Connection
                                  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                                  Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

              String query1="select distinct(date) FROM `report_data` WHERE date>= ? and date<= ? "; //Query one for date input 
               PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query1);

               System.out.println("Enter the 1st DATE"); //Date 1 is entered 
                date1 = b.readLine();
                System.out.println("Enter the 2nd DATE"); //Date 2 is entered 
                date2=b.readLine();
                                    ps.setString(1,date1);
                ps.setString(2,date2);
                         System.out.println("enter the param_code"); // param_code is entered 
                p_code= b.readLine();

               ResultSet result=ps.executeQuery();  
                          System.out.print("Tow_id");
                         while(result.next() )
                        {
                          getdate=result.getString("date");
                          System.out.print("\t"+getdate);
                    date3='%'+getdate+'%';
                                    date[x]=date3;
                    x++;
                         }
                          l=x;


              String query2="SELECT distinct(tow_id) FROM  `tower_data` WHERE TIME_STAMP LIKE ? "; //query 2 for finding tower-id 
                                   PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(query2);
                ps1.setString(1,date[0]);      
                ResultSet result1=ps1.executeQuery(); 



                while(result1.next())
                 { 
                  System.out.println("");
                  tower=result1.getString("tow_id");
                   tower1= Integer.parseInt(tower);
            tow[z]=tower1;

                 t=y;
                 System.out.print(tower1);
                           int count=0;
                 x=0;
                 request.getSession().setAttribute("tower_id", tow);

                           while(count<l)
                   {
                          String query3="SELECT time_stamp FROM tower_data WHERE `TIME_STAMP` LIKE ? AND `PARAM_CODE` = ? AND `TOW_ID`=? GROUP BY time_stamp HAVING count( * ) >1";
                                       //Query 3 for finding time stamps with duplicate data 
                    PreparedStatement ps2=con.prepareStatement(query3); 
                    ps2.setString(2,p_code);
                     ps2.setString(1,date[x]);
                    ps2.setInt(3,tower1);
                    ResultSet result2=ps2.executeQuery();

                                       int row=0;
                                      while(result2.next())
                  {

                  t_split=result2.getString("time_stamp");

                 String[] parts= t_split.split(" "); //splitting time_stamp to extract only time without date 
                                      time2=parts[1]; //time stored in time2
                System.out.println("\t"+time2);
                row++;

                }
               if(row==0)
                                    {
                                    System.out.println("\t"+"no duplicate");                        
                }
                       System.out.print("\t"+"\t");



                                  x++;
             count++;
                   }       




        }
        con.close();


                          }
                         catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                        }



                       }
```

And finally this is the **output JSP page** which has to show the output from the Java class:

```
<%@page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<html>
  <body>
    You entered<BR>
Date1: <%= duplicaterecords.getDate1() %><BR>
Date2: <%= duplicaterecords.getDate2() %><BR>
PARAM CODE: <%= duplicaterecords.getP_code() %><BR>
 <table border="1">
<tr><td><B>Tower ID:</B></td></tr>
<%
ArrayList towerArray = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("tower_id");
String myString="";
for(int i = 0; i < towerArray.size(); i++)
{
myString = (String) towerArray.get(i);

}

%> 
<tr><td><%=myString%></td></tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: what does the documentation of `NullPointerException` say?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the Exception?

Comment: Read some Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: @adarshr why did you said so?

Comment: adarshr comments on your names, for example "duplicaterecords" instead of "DuplicateRecords". Not relevant to the question.

Comment: @MRalwasser this is the **root cause**

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.Nextpage_jsp._jspService(Nextpage_jsp.java:110)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)`

Comment: @MRalwasser
**exception**

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:541)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:435)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)`

Comment: @Anurag: Open the compiled Nextpage_jsp.java (often placed in a work folder), go to the line 110 and identify which line is causing the NPE.

Comment: @adashr @Aleadam I accept the n00bness in naming conventions.

Comment: @BalusC @MRalwasser Strange as I opened the Nextpage.jsp in notepad++ and there are 49 lines of code. That is the last piece of code I have included in the question :|

Comment: @Anurag: You have to open **Nextpage_jsp.java**, not Nextpage.jsp

Comment: @Anurag: as I said above, the naming convention is not really relevant to solve the problem. I do not understand why you got two downvotes. It seems lately that you can't post a question in here unless you already know the answer... In any case, check MeBigFatGuy's reply because he has very good points. As I said in my reply (although for the wrong reason probably), I think you are using the variables in the jsp file before being initialized by the servlet.

Comment: (continuation) My advice for the sake of learning is to create a small, independent project with very simple code, accessing only one string variable in the jsp file so you can pinpoint the issue easier, rather than being complicated by those int arrays and ArrayLists.

Comment: @Aleadam I agree with you. Still on the big learning curve. And as I am new to StackOverflow can't cry about downvotes. Everything for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the actual error so it is just a guess but you are doing:

`request.getSession().setAttribute("tower_id", tow);`

where tow is an int array.

Then in the JSP, you are saying:

`ArrayList towerArray = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("tower_id");`

So those types aren't compatible.

Also, unrelated to your question I would advise you that the code quality in general seems to be quite bad. I would suggest reading more about Java conventions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

in action
    request.getSession().setAttribute("tower_id", tow);

in jsp

```
ArrayList towerArray = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("tower_id");
```

but tow is an array

```
int l,x=0,y=0,tow[],i=0,z=0,tower1=0,t=0;
```

but beyond all that, why is there a main method that's static in your servlet code, and where is the doGet or doPost?

Which is why you are seeing the NPE and not a class cast exception. There is no tower_id attribute in your session, and so when you do this

```
towerArray.size()
```

you get the NPE